# How can I obtain older versions of Xcode?

Tags: snow-leopard, development, xcode

How can I obtain older versions of Xcode?

Is there a way that I can freely download a version that only requires OS X 10.6.8? So far [this](http://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/) is all I've found on the matter; but, when I click the 'download Xcode 3' link, it simply brings up the page for downloading version 4.

Comment: Have tried looking for a torrent?

Comment: Wouldn't that be considered illegal?

Comment: I'dve thought its about as legal as your copy of OS X 10.6 - generally OS X distributions on DVD include a copy of XCode that will run on your OS version. Have you checked?

Failing that a friend could lend you their installer.

Comment: @5arx: "I'dve thought its about as legal as your copy of OS X 10.6..." That makes no sense of any kind. When has Apple *ever* had torrents as an official method of distribution?

Comment: I was under the impression that nowadays OS X installers come with a secondary disc which includes a copy of Xcode for that version of the OS. My point being that if one has legally installed OS X 10.6 he *should* also have a compatible XCode installer thus negating the need to find one from other sources.

Comment: I'll have to check my disk.. I've never put it in my computer...

Comment: @MatthewFrederick, I haven't gotten many correct answers to my questions.. But I'll check again, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 13):

You can download **[older versions of Xcode here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/)** after you've logged into the dev center.

Uncheck all of the options except "Developer Tools" in the Categories section on the left side of the page. Every version of Xcode back to version 1.0 in 2003 is available there.

Comment: I'm not registered as an Apple developer though..

Comment: @JamesLitewski up to the App Store you always had to be registered - it is free

Comment: You cannot obtain it, if you are not registered as developer.

Comment: Oh okay, I guess I'll have to find the money to register..

Comment: @James: free registration will do.

Comment: @Peter, thanks I just figured that out for myself last night :) But if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @JamesLitewski If you register for free, how do you download XCode 3? It's not there, no links to it in the dev portal. The only option I know of: click on the link provided in this answer.

Comment: For anyone wondering about @MatthewFrederick 's question, login to the Mac developer portal, and search the page for "View all downloads". Click on this link and search for the version you need.

Comment: Funnily enough, I just re-downloaded Xcode 4 following this same path yesterday.

Comment: web page not available. Also, I am having so much trouble downloading anything on an older mac. All of this version stuff is maddness. I could not be more dissatisfied if I want to do more than browse the web or use Microsoft Word or some Adobe crap. I'm sorry, but it is so true. Oh yeah ... one more thing. Mac moves all of it's links around, so that people like me cannot find links posted by people like you! THANKS MAC! Your're amazing. A truly inspiring way to maintain an operating system.

Comment: Replaced the link with a better one, @Dylan.

Answer (score 8):

To get a free older copy of Xcode that will run on Snow Leopard, create(register) as an Apple Developer at this web site https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/ .  You can also turn your current Apple ID into a developer ID by signing in on the link above and following the instructions.

After you create your Developer ID go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads

On the upper left side of the page search for Xcode  and just below the search box, uncheck all of the Catagories except Developer Tools (leave that checked).

You will get three pages of results, on the second page you will find Xcode in version 3 for Snow Leopard.

Cheers
rws70

Answer (score 2):

`xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg` is the name of the file I am downloading currently.

I registered for free as an apple developer at https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/ and then searched for 'xcode' in the downloads section.

I am on snow leopard, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 3 requires a version of snow leopard (10.6.8) :D. However, do you still have your snow leopard disc? if so, re-install it because xcode 3 comes pre-installed with sow leopard.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Xcode doesn't get installed automatically but you can run the installer from the DVD.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth for anyone else that ends up here; the bundle linked above:
http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792

Doesn't exist anymore, but there is a way to get 3.2.6 - through developer.apple.com/downloads - after free registration filter for 'developer tools' and type xcode - you should find the xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg others have mentioned.  It's 4+ GB though...

It's a shame you can't get it without IOS but for those of us stuck with snow leopard (despite mavericks now being free) 3.2.6 seems neccesary for brew - the package management tool.

Answer (score -1):

Go to App Store, click Purcharsed, and check if you see 'Xcode for Snow Leopard' there. I have it there, but maybe it's because I've bought Xcode 4.0 when it was released and there was no Lion yet.

Answer (score -1):

it's available!

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg

XCode for Mac Snow Leopard

Comment: That is a dead link for me: "Your session has expired..."

Comment: See several other answers as to how to get that link